# i am bulding web app the text box that is created in runtime and save data in database asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Here is the code that i am write it is not working well please check my problem an reply as soon as possible

```
    //HomeController.cs
    using checkinsert.Models;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace checkinsert.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                List<Table> ci = new List<Table> {new Table {Id=0,name="",contactno=""} };
                return View();
            }
            [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public ActionResult Index(List<Table> ci)
            {
                if(ModelState.IsValid){
                using(Database1Entities dc= new Database1Entities())
                {
                    foreach(var i in ci)
                    {
                    dc.Tables.Add(i);

                    }
                    dc.SaveChanges();
                ViewBag.Message="Data is Successful inserted";
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    ci= new List<Table>{new Table{Id=0,name="",contactno=""}};
                }
                }
                return View(ci);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the Index.cshtml and the problem is that text field are not showing in browser means when we run then there is no text field show

And also check the path of jquery file i feel that there is an problem in the path of j query file because j query file is not running ...

```
    @model List<checkinsert.Models.Table>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Insert Bulk Data";
    }

    <div style="width:720px;padding:5px;background-color:white;">
       @using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Home",FormMethod.Get))
       { 
           @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
           @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
           if(ViewBag.Message!=null)
           {
               <div style="border:1px solid green">
                   @ViewBag.Message
               </div>
           }
           <div><a href="#" id="AddNew" >Add New</a></div>
       <table id="dataTable" border="0" >
           <tr>
               <th>Contact Name</th>
               <th>Contact No</th>
            </tr>

           @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
           {
               int j = 0;
               foreach (var i in Model)
               { 

               <tr style="border:1px solid black">
                   <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a[j].name)</td>
                   <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a[j].contactno)</td>
             <td>
                 @if(j>0)
                 {
                 <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
                 }
             </td>
                     </tr>
                   j++;
               }
           }
               </table>
           <input type="submit" value="Save Data" />
       }
    </div>
    @* here is the JQuery code *@
    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("checkinsert/jquery-3.0.0.min.js")
        <script lang="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#addNew").click(function () {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var $tablebody = $("#dataTable");
                    var $trLast = $tablebody.find("tr:last");
                    var $trNew = $trLast.clone();
                    var $suffix = $trNew.find(':input:first').attr('name').match(/\d+/);
                    $trNew.find("td:last").html('<a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>');
                    $.each($trNew.find(':input'), function (i, val) {
                        // Replaced Name
                        var $oldN = $(this).attr('name');
                        var $newN = $oldN.replace('[' + suffix + ']', '[' + (parseInt(suffix) + 1) + ']');
                        $(this).attr('name',nawN);
                        //Replaced value
                        var type = $(this).attr('type');
                        if (type.toLowerCase == "text")
                        {
                            $(this).attr('value', '');
                            // if you have another type then replaced this "text" with default value
                            $(this).removeClass("input-validation-error");
                        }
                    });
                    $trLast.after($trNew);
                    // re-assign validation
                    var form = $("form")
                    .removeData("validator")
                    .removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
                    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
                });

                // 2.remove
                $('a.remove').live("click", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                });
            });
        </script>
        }
```

Comment: check the answer and test it, waitting your feedback

Answer (score 0):

There are two problem in your code

1. You don't send model after create it in Get

   ```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       List<Table> ci = new List<Table> {new Table {Id=0,name="",contactno=""} };
       return View(ci);
   }
   ```
2. foreach in view, you don't need counter you already in for loop.

   ```
   @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
       {
           foreach (var tabel in Model)
           {
               <tr style="border:1px solid black">
                   <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => tabel.name)</td>
                   <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => tabel.contactno)</td>
                   <td>
                       <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
                   </td>
               </tr>
           }
       }
   ```

Comment: I can't understand your answer please EXPLAIN in detail or send the solution

Comment: your view take model  `List<checkinsert.Models.Table>`, in mvc when you return view take model, you must pass it, you created it but didn't pass it  `return View(ci);`

Comment: and replce your foreach loop in your view with my answer

Comment: Thanks bro some how a program is running good but their is one more problem in the code that if i replace our loop with your loop then remove link is not display OR one more problem is that when i click one Add New link then it is not working I think so may be problem in the j query file path please check it ... @Scripts.Render("jquery-3.0.0.min.js")

Comment: Tell me please one more problem in another program i use mvc ORM model and i want to find unique values form database table...

Comment: for unique value i use this code                                                                     var a = obj2.Mcqs.Distinct(x => x.cla.Equals(name));
            return View(a.ToList());

Comment: Create new questions with these inquires and problems and IF my answer solved your problem marked as solved so others when searching about same problem can use answer, but you can't keep asking new questions in comments :) .. OK !